Trying to do IEC 61000-4-5 simulation with Pspice. Which circuit is correct?
I am working as an Electrical engineer in South Korea.
My first language is not English. I am sorry.
I want to perform IEC 61000-4-5 simulation with Pspice.
Can you tell me which of the two circuits below is the right one?
(DC 523V is the input voltage of the product and the other is the 1.2/50 uSec surge voltage.)
Thank you for your response in advance.



This is the right one, The injection is done in differential mode with 18uf capacitor and 2 Ohm

